# Full calendar custom button is undefined

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular8, fullcalendar-scheduler

I Have tried to create a Full calendar with a bootstrap theme. Implementation success. but I added a custom button with icon 'fa fa-clock-o'. But the icon can't show. showing `undefined`
My Options like

```
this.options = {
      customButtons: {
        myCustomButton: {
          icon: "fa fa-clock-o",
          click: () => this.picker.open()
        }
      },
      header: {
        right: 'prev next today',
        left: 'title',
        center: 'myCustomButton dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      }
}
```

Inspect that button it showing like

```
<button type="button" class="fc-myCustomButton-button btn btn-primary" undefined="">undefined</button>
```

help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am bad with css but...
Are you sure this "fa fa-clock-o" is a image and not a css class ?
This would work : <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Time</button>
You can lookup the classdefinition and check what the actual icon is

Comment: @CR92 fullCalendar allows you to set a font-awesome class from which to read the icon data. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/customButtons, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/buttonIcons, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/bootstrapFontAwesome . However I suspect OP should be specifying just `fa-clock-o` instead of `fa fa-clock-o`

Comment: @CR92 I Tried it too. But it showing undefined only

Comment: @VelusamyVenkatraman Try specifying just `icon: "fa-clock-o"` instead of `icon: "fa fa-clock-o"` . P.S. are you using the fullCalendar bootstrap theme? Have you loaded font-awesome files? It would only work if you do those things as well.

Comment: @ADyson Can you look at the inspect stuff. There is no icon created. I used bootstrap theme only. But the other icons are working. Like "fa fa-chevron-left", "fa fa-chevron-left" are working

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution? I have a similar problem. I only want to change the click method but the text become in "undefined". @VelusamyVenkatraman